# Unable to filter the unique value using distinctUntilChanged() from the input stream

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Need your help. I am new to Rxjs world and am trying to use distinctUntilChanged() operator to avoid duplicate values received from stream through input box. But I could not see any difference in the output. May be i have miss-understood the explanation by rxjs docs.
Below is the url where I am trying to demonstrate this example. 
It will be great if you could help me with the little explanation and changes where I am suppose to make in the code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1yhec?file=src%2Fapp%2Frxjs-check%2Frxjs-check.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {


const inputObs$ =
  fromEvent<any>(this.inputVal.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    map(res => res.target.value),
    //tap(char => console.log(char)),
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(char => console.log(char)),
    map(text => this.fnGetDbData(text))
  )

inputObs$.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
  this.dbPlace = res;

});
```

}

Comment: Please specify your question in your title and reduce the amount of code in your blitz to the minimum required to exemplify your issue/query.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo First of all than you for your response, I have changed the title as you suggested. Now the issue is I am trying to filter the duplicate value which is coming from input stream.

Comment: _But I could not see any difference in the output._ Specify? What input did you tried? If I type _a_, wait for the debounce, then delete it and type _a_ again, only 1 value is emitted, the first _a_

Comment: What output are you expecting? The `distinctUntilChanged` works as it should in your example. It never lets the same value through twice directly one after another.

Comment: Got it. Thanks you so much for your support. It seems like I was a bit confused with the Operator. I thought if I type multiple a then only one a will be published in the output.

Comment: Honestly, I could not find any use of distinctUntilChanged operator here, even i remove it, i am getting the same output.

Comment: You're mapping to `res.target.value` which is the whole string in your text field not just the last typed character. So `distincUntilChanged` looks at the whole string in your text field. If you quickly type `a` & `backspace` within the debounce time of 1 second you'll see that nothing gets emitted as the whole input text is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubts.